# Improving JavaScript code in a view file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to know how I can *refactor*, *DRY* (Don't Repeat Yourself) and *improve* the following code in my view file:

```
<% articles.each do |article| %>

  <div>
    <%= link_to 'add', '#', :id => "create_#{article.id}" %>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    # Code - Block 1
    $jQ('#create_<%= article.id %>').live('click', function(event) {
      $jQ.ajax({
        type:    "POST",
        url:     "<%= article_url(@article) %>/create",
        data:    "article_id=<%= @article.id %>",
        error:   function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown + '\n\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          $jQ('#create_<%= article.id %>').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript("added") + (link_to 'remove', '#', :id => "destroy_#{article.id}") %>')
        }
      });
    });

    # Code - Block 2
    $jQ('#destroy_<%= .id %>').live('click', function(event) {
      $jQ.ajax({
        type:    "POST",
        url:     "<%= article_url(@article) %>/destroy",
        data:    "article_id=<%= @article.id %>,
        error:   function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown + '\n\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          $jQ('#destroy_<%= article.id %>').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript("removed") + (link_to 'add', '#', :id => "create_#{article.id}") %>')
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

<% end %>
```

*Note*:

- The `each` statement!
- The "two code blocks" above are almost equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is nest another array of methods inside of your article loop, and use it to tweak the inner code block for each method accordingly.

Here's an example: (untested but should be close)

```
<% articles.each do |article| %>

  <div>
    <%= link_to 'add', '#', :id => "create_#{article.id}" %>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    <% [:create,:destroy].each do |method| %>
          $jQ('#<%="#{method}_#{article.id}" %>').live('click', function(event) {
            $jQ.ajax({.   
              type:    "POST",
              url:     "<%= "#{article_url(@article)}/#{method}" %>",
              data:    "article_id=<%= @article.id %>",
              error:   function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown + '\n\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
              },
              success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $jQ('#<%="#{method}_#{article.id}" %>').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript({'create'=>'added','destroy'=>'removed'}[method]) + (link_to( {'create'=>'add','destroy'=>'remove'}[method], '#', :id => "#{method}_#{article.id}")) %>')
              }
            });
          });

    <% end %>
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Your other options are to turn this into a helper method that takes an article and a method and generates the correct output, or you can put the necessary data in the html tags and have javascript convert it.

Comment: I think I would loop wtih `[[:create, 'added'], [:destroy, 'removed']].each do |method, message|`, just to keep the definitions all in one place.

Comment: The above is what I tried to say.  The thing to take away, is yes, you were duplicating your code, but you might come to find that duplication was necessary down the line as the two events could turn out to be very different w/ callbacks and other stuff - keep that in mind.  While it's nice to reduce lines, it's not always beneficial.  Looping will also require more processing (time).

Answer (score 1):

- Put the main body in a string
- Have an array of arrays for two iterations (one with `['create','added','remove',destroy']` and the other with `['destroy','removed','add','create']`)
- Loop twice (0..1), interpolating your array values for those slots where the text is found

  - First Pass: `array[0][0], array[0][0], array[0][0], array[0][1], array[0][2], array[0][3]`
  - Second Pass: `array[1][0], array[1][0], array[1][0], array[1][1], array[1][2], array[1][3]`

---

***Note:** my Ruby is rusty, so here's the pseudo code.*
Example (look for `ary[i][n]`):

```
ary = [['create','added','remove',destroy'],
       ['destroy','removed','add','create']]

for i in (0..1)
   $jQ('#**ary[i][0]_<%= article.id %>').live('click', function(event) {
      $jQ.ajax({
         type:    "POST",
         url:     "<%= article_url(@article) %>/ary[i][0]",
         data:    "article_id=<%= @article.id %>",
         error:   function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown + '\n\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                  },
         success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                     $jQ('#ary[i][0]_<%= article.id %>')
                        .replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript("ary[i][1]") + (link_to 'ary[i][2]', '#', :id => "ary[i][3]_#{article.id}") %>')
                  }
      });
   });
end
```

Comment: I didn't understand your approach at all (maybe because I am a newbie). What do you mean with 'array[0][0], array[0][0], array[0][0], ...' and 'array[1][0], array[1][0], array[1][0], ...'? How should I "loop" for array[loopCountVar]?

Comment: I meant, you'll be calling the first array element three times in your string.  I don't remember any Ruby, so I wasn't going to supply the example code, but I found my statement confusing, so I put some pseudocode.

Comment: you would put the above in something like `for i in (0..1)`...`end`. I've edited the code above to demonstrate.  Note: the loop and array would be Ruby-code - I'll let you figure out how the interpolation goes.